# Remove whitespace above a single stacked bar in CanvasJS

Tags: charts, canvasjs

I have created a horizontal stacked bar using CanvasJS. But the scaling bothers me.

If you look to http://www.vandeel.com/dashboard/canvasjs.html I have created to examples; 1 with 300px height and 1 with 100px height. The first results in a lot of whitespace above the bar, the second is unreadable. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/

How to create a readable, one bar solution with a height of 100 pixels?

Kind regards,
Martijn

**HTML**

```
<br/><!-- Just so that JSFiddle's Result label doesn't overlap the Chart -->

<div id="budgetbar" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("budgetbar",
{
  animationEnabled: true,
  axisX: {     
    interval: 0,
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 0,
    indexLabelFontSize: 50
  },
  axisY: {     
    interval: 10000,
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 105000,
    valueFormatString: "€ #,###,###",
    gridThickness: 0,
    gridColor: "#ffffff",
    tickLength: 3,
    indexLabelFontSize: 50
  },
  data: [
    {        
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Verbruikt",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 27000, color: "#cc33bb", toolTipContent: "€ 30.000 Spent" }
        ]
    },
    {        
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Prognose V",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 500, color: "#fc9935", toolTipContent: "€ 27.500 Prognose V" }
        ]
    },
    {        
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Verbruikt",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 2500, color: "#cc33bb", toolTipContent: "€ 30.000 Spent" }
        ]
    },
    {        
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Budget",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 64500, color: "#EEEEEE", toolTipContent: "€ 100.000 Budget" }
        ]
    },
    {
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Prognose T",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 500, color: "#999900", toolTipContent: "€ 95.000 Prognose" }
        ]
    },
    {        
    type: "stackedBar",
    name: "Budget",
    showInLegend: "false",
    dataPoints: [
        { x:1, y: 5000, color: "#EEEEEE", toolTipContent: "€ 100.000 Budget" }
        ]
    }
  ]
  ,
  legend:{
    cursor:"pointer",
    itemclick:function(e) {
      if(typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible){
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
      }
      else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
      }

      chart.render();
    }
  }
});

chart.render();
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is because of the **maximum** & **interval** that you have set on axisY. It should work fine when you remove the same. And you can make small charts readable by setting [labelFontSize](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/labelfontsize/) of axis and [fontSize](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/legend/fontsize/) property of legend. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwZuf/265/).

```
      axisX:{
          labelFontSize: 10
      },
      axisY:{
          labelFontSize: 10
      }
```